# How to fix a value of variable once got from sensor

Tags: c++, arduino

everyone, I am working on a project where I have an Arduino getting analog values from the potentiometer, there is a switch also which when pressed should read the current pot value and then fix it until the button is released i.e. now change in pot value will not show any change in output unless button is released.

```
const int pedal = A1;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
const int high_pitch_fail =5 ;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
  hpf = digitalRead(high_pitch_fail);
  pedalValue = analogRead(pedal);
  if (hpf==LOW)
  {
   hpf_pedal=pedalValue;
   outputValue= hpf_pedal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

update the analog value continuously while the button is not pressed

update the analog value only the moment the button is pressed

Which one suits your needs best I cannot tell. It depends on wether you want to keep updating while the button is released or if you're only interested in having a constant value while the button is pressed.